# hard time enabling openldap meta backend

Tags: openldap

Right now I'm feeling stuck with enabling meta backend using openldap 2,4

this is the result of my slaptest

```
[root@localhost openldap]# slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d/

    WARNING: No dynamic config support for database meta.

    WARNING: The converted cn=config directory is incomplete and may not work.
```

but in my centos 6,3 machine there's no "meta" module to add or include.

My sandbox is a clean centos 6,3 install, I've installed openldap-servers and openldap-clients , is there anything else that need to be installed in order to get meta working?

this is my slap.conf file:

```
include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema

database meta
suffix "dc=int,dc=test,dc=com"
uri     "ldap://int.test.com/dc=int,dc=test,dc=com"
```

The uri exist in my sandbox network.

help!

Answer (score 0):

`cn=config` support for `back-meta` was added in OpenLDAP 2.4.33. If you run an older version you'll have to use `slapd.conf`.

The [changelog](http://www.openldap.org/software/release/changes.html) also mentions a variety of other fixes to `back-meta` in subsequent releases.

If you're not prepared to build the current OpenLDAP release from source, the [LTB-Project](http://ltb-project.org/) provides up-to-date RPM packages.